# How can i pickle QPixmap

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pickle, qpixmap

I've a class that stores QPixmap that are cpu comsumming to generate. I'd like to pickle it so that it can be reused from one session to the next one without recomputing from innitial image (theres some resize and heavy operation).

QPixmap is not pickable so it doesn't work but i noticed that QByteArray is pickable. So i tried to implement a '**getstate**', '**setstate**' workaround. See below.

```
class StoreQPixmap:

    def __init__(self):
        # store QPixmap computed image - It is a dictionary as several images can 
         be stored for the same picture and
        # the dictionary key is the way to distinguish them
        self._qpixmap = {}


    def set_qpixmap(self, hash_, qpixmap):
        self._qpixmap[hash_] = qpixmap

    def get_qpixmap(self, hash_):
        try:
            return self._qpixmap[hash_]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def del_qpixmap(self, hash_):
        try:
            del self._qpixmap[hash_]
            return True
        except KeyError:
            return False

    def __getstate__(self):
        # QPixmap is not pickable so let's transform it into QByteArray that does support pickle
        state = []
        qbyte_array = QByteArray()
        buffer = QBuffer(qbyte_array)
        for key, value in self._qpixmap.items():
            buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            value.save(buffer, 'PNG')
            state.append((key,buffer))
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # retrieve a QByteArray and transform it into QPixmap
        qpixmap = QPixmap()
        for key, buffer in state:
            qpixmap.loadFromData(buffer)
            self._qpixmap[key] = qpixmap
```

But in order to translate QPixmap to QByteArray it seems i need a QBuffer..that is not pickable and i'm back to initial issue :-(

Can any one point me on what could be the approach to implement Qpixmap pickle by transforming the object to "something that is pickable"

Thanks

Comment: The list you return should include the byte arrays, not the buffers. Also, you should create a new byte array and buffer each iteration of the loop.

Comment: If you want to serialize a pixmap, use [QDatastream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#operator-lt-lt).

Comment: Thanks guys. It does work fine with QDatastream. Code adapted below

Answer (score 1):

Updated code with QDatastream below

```
class StoreQPixmap:

def __init__(self):
    # store QPixmap computed image - It is a dictionary as several images can be stored for the same picture and
    # the dictionary key is the way to distinguish them
    self._qpixmap = {}

   def __getstate__(self):
    # QPixmap is not pickable so let's transform it into QByteArray that does support pickle
    state = []
    for key, value in self._qpixmap.items():
        qbyte_array = QByteArray()
        stream = QDataStream(qbyte_array, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        stream << value
        state.append((key, qbyte_array))
    return state

def __setstate__(self, state):

    self._qpixmap = {}
    # retrieve a QByteArray and transform it into QPixmap
    for (key, buffer) in state:
        qpixmap = QPixmap()
        stream = QDataStream(buffer, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        stream >> qpixmap
        self._qpixmap[key] = qpixmap
```